# How to Batch resize images with PHP

Tags: php, batch-processing

I am maintaining an old website. Now my client wants to add more than 6000 products. The product images have different sizes. I have to apply batch process. I have to resize them all to a thumb size of 230x230. Is there any way to do if from PHP?  If so how?

I have to read all content from different folders which are inside a main images folders. This images folder has 40 subfolders. Each folder name is the category name and the images inside it are products (image).

```
if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $NewImage,0, 0, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $iWidth, $iHeight))
{
    // copy file
    if(imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestImage,$Quality))
    {
        imagedestroy($NewCanves);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course there are ways to do that – but if you trigger this via an HTTP request and want to it run over all files in one go, you will most likely run into execution time and probably memory limits. Would be better to do this from command line, if you have access – and then it does not have to be in PHP, tools like Imagick allow batch conversions as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With php you can read the files inside a folder using

```
$images= glob("*"); // * will address all files
// or
$images= glob("*.jpg"); // this will address only jpg images
```

Then loop through $images

```
foreach ($images as $filename) {
   //resize the image
   if(resizeImage($imagePath,$destPath,$NewImageWidth,$NewImageHeight,$Quality)){
     echo $filename.' resize Success!<br />';
   }
}

function resizeImage($SrcImage,$DestImage, $MaxWidth,$MaxHeight,$Quality)
{
    list($iWidth,$iHeight,$type)    = getimagesize($SrcImage);

    //if you dont want to rescale image

    $NewWidth=$MaxWidth;
    $NewHeight=$MaxHeight;
    $NewCanves              = imagecreatetruecolor($NewWidth, $NewHeight);

    // Resize Image
    if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $NewImage,0, 0, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $iWidth, $iHeight))
     {
        // copy file
        if(imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestImage,$Quality))
        {
            imagedestroy($NewCanves);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are welcome. So where were you stuck bytheway. You can also read the directories inside indrectories using $folder = "images";
$results = scandir($folder);

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with a shell script but if you must do it in PHP I would stick all the images into the same directory and loop through it with..

```
$img= new Imagick($srcpath);
$img->resizeImage($width,$height,Imagick::FILTER_BOX,1,true);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-resizeimage.php

Answer (score 1):

You can easily resize single/multiple images with this library. there are only 4-5 lines of PHP code so you can manage easily.

Also, the ability to pass many other options in parameter like height,  width, img_dir.

https://github.com/hsleonis/image-resizer

`require_once ('class.imageresizer.php');`

```
// Create thumbnails
$args = array(
    'height'    => 975,
    'width'     => 650,
    'is_crop_hard' => 1
);
$img = new ImageResizer($args);
$img->create();</code>
```